# unknown protocol error in connection to repo.magento.com:443

Tags: magento2, error, ssl, marketplace

I get the following error after downloading the cacert.pem file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem   and adding curl.cainfo=C:/xampp/Apache/cacert.pem  in php.ini file

[image]

Comment: Do you have cURL enabled on xampp?

Comment: yes it is enabled..still creating the problem..

Comment: Which version of cULR are you using? This problem happens because of outdated cURL . Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384161/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-t

Comment: version is not creating the problem...any other better suggestion?

Comment: Please check this https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Extensions/Unknown-SSL-protocol-error-in-connection-to-connect20/m-p/41660#M594

Comment: I m working on windows ..so plz give the solution corresponding to it

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved by changing registry values:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL2.0\Client
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000(0)